# Starting an Apache Spark cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, configuration, installation

I've installed Hadoop on my four node cluster.  I've also installed Apache Spark on each of them. I can ssh without a password from the master into each of the slaves.  I can also start up my master node just fine.  However, when I try to run Spark with /opt/spark/sbin/start-all.sh, I get the following error:

```
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-lebron.out
doublet: chown: changing ownership of ‘/opt/spark/logs’: Operation not permitted
doublet: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-doublet.out
doublet: /opt/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh: line 149: /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-doublet.out: Permission denied
kyrie: chown: changing ownership of ‘/opt/spark/logs’: Operation not permitted
kyrie: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-kyrie.out
kyrie: /opt/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh: line 149: /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-kyrie.out: Permission denied
lebron: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-lebron.out
jr: chown: changing ownership of ‘/opt/spark/logs’: Operation not permitted
jr: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-jr.out
jr: /opt/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh: line 149: /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-jr.out: Permission denied
doublet: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
doublet: tail: cannot open ‘/opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-doublet.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
doublet: full log in /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-doublet.out
kyrie: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
kyrie: tail: cannot open ‘/opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-kyrie.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
jr: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
kyrie: full log in /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-kyrie.out
jr: tail: cannot open ‘/opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-jr.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
jr: full log in /opt/spark/logs/spark-hduser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-jr.out
```

(My computers are named lebron (master), kyrie, jr, doublet (workers))

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look likes the /opt/spark folder does not have permission to writing into log file 
give the full permission :-
   **sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/spark**
and also check that /opt/spark  folder user:group have same value for all the machine (master and slaves both) otherwise run this command
   **sudo chown -R userName:groupName /opt/spark**

Answer (score 4):

Starting the Server:

To start a standalone master server execute:

```
$ ./sbin/start-master.sh
```

To start one or more workers and connect them to the master via:

```
$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh <master-spark-URL>
```

Take a look at this article: [Apache Spark Cluster Installation and Configuration Guide](http://codeflex.co/apache-spark-cluster-installation-and-configuration-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

configure password less ssh on all nodes.